# Is Aqeeqah compulsory for parents?

Tags: aqeeqah

I am expecting a baby in this month (IN SHA ALLAH) and i want to do aqeeqahbut financially i need to pay a loan and in march the zakat is pending. So it would be difficult for me to do aqeeqah. I cannot do it within seven days. I have read that it is pledge for Muslim to do aqeeqahfor new born baby. So what should i do?

Comment: Aqeeqah is Sunnah. It can be performed after seven days, I've seen people perform it a couple of months or even years later. What you should do is subjective and not answerable, we don't know your complete financial situation.

Answer (score 1):

Al-salam 'alaykum.

Firstly, al-hamdulillah for your new baby; may Allah SWT bless you and your family.

From what I have understood, Aqeeqah is only a mustahhab action and it is neither wajib nor fardh. Therefore, if you do not have the financial means to perform Aqeeqah, you are not obliged to.

Furthermore, I heard that although the preferred time for slaughtering the animal is on the seventh day, if this is not possible, then it should be done on the fourteenth day; if this is not possible either then the twenty-first day.

I have summarised this answer from [islamQA.org](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/84884); if you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Finally, Allah SWT knows best.